# codeignater mail function not working on shared hosting server

Tags: php, codeigniter, hosting, sendmail

```php
$this->load->library('email');
//Email content
$htmlContent = '<h1>Don`t worry, we all forget sometimes </h1>';
$htmlContent .= '<p>Hi,</p>';
$htmlContent .= '<p>You`ve recently asked to reset the password for this account</p>';
$htmlContent .= '<span>Your Forgot Otp Is :</span>';
$this->email->to($email);
$this->email->from('abc@gmail.com','abc');
$this->email->subject('Forget Password');
$this->email->message("$htmlContent"." "."<p><h2>$forgotOtp</h2></p>"."<p>Thanks,</p>"."<p>Team</p>"." "." <p> abc<p>");
          //Send email
$this->email->send();

$this->ApiModel->UpdateForgotOtp($email,$forgotOtp);
print_r(json_encode([
        'message'=>'success',
       'status'=>200
]));
```

this code is not working on sharing host server.no error message will display

Comment: Did you checked the error logs and tried with sending a normal mail via server. If still it does not helps use try-catch exception to get what exact error you are getting. Check this url hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34381233/mail-not-sending-from-hosted-codeigniter-application

Comment: "this code is not working" is not enough be more specific & post the exact error you are getting then only anybody will be able to help you out.

Comment: sir i also try with this link but email not sent

Comment: @RopAliMunshi sir after sending mail success message is printed .no error will display

Comment: @Mr. vinod post your full code.

Comment: @RopAliMunshi sir full code is updated please check

Comment: @Mr.vinod I don't see the `$this->email->initialize()` line where you are initializing the email library. This may be the issue.

Comment: @RopAliMunshi sir i am autoload the email library in config file.

Comment: @Mr.vinod but the first line says that you are loading the library there itself.

Comment: @RopAliMunshi sir what i can do now?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set up the configurations to send the email like this,

```
$config = array(
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'YOUR_HOST',
    'smtp_port' => 2525,
    'smtp_user' => 'USERNAME',
    'smtp_pass' => 'PASSWORD',
    'crlf' => "\r\n",
    'newline' => "\r\n"
);
$this->load->library('email');

// Initialize the library
$this->email->initialize($config );

//Email content
$htmlContent = '<h1>Don`t worry, we all forget sometimes </h1>';
$htmlContent .= '<p>Hi,</p>';
$htmlContent .= '<p>You`ve recently asked to reset the password for this account</p>';
$htmlContent .= '<span>Your Forgot Otp Is :</span>';
$this->email->to($email);
$this->email->from('abc@gmail.com','abc');
$this->email->subject('Forget Password');
$this->email->message("$htmlContent"." "."<p><h2>$forgotOtp</h2></p>"."<p>Thanks,</p>"."<p>Team</p>"." "." <p> abc<p>");
          //Send email
$this->email->send();

$this->ApiModel->UpdateForgotOtp($email,$forgotOtp);
print_r(json_encode([
        'message'=>'success',
       'status'=>200
]));
```

Comment: sir,  this code is also not working on share hosting